# Remembering Users Email Address for Login Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, session-cookies

When a customer types in an incorrect password, I've set it up so that the email address they type is remembered and pre-populated when the login page loads again.

I've done this using the sessions module like this:

```
session[:email] = params[:session][:email]
```

My login form looks like this:

```
      <%= simple_form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :email, input_html: {value: session[:email]} %>

        <% if session[:email] != nil %>
          <%= f.input :password, :autofocus => true %>
        <% else %>
          <%= f.input :password %>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %>
      <% end %>
```

**Are there any security concerns with this type of approach?**

Comment: You're mispelling `required` in your `f.input` options.

Comment: @muistooshort nice catch

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I would say no since the email address is provided by the user in the first place.  It's not as if you are pulling the email from some random record in the database and displaying it for them without any prompts from the user.

However, this could be potentially concerning if a user attempts to log onto your site from a public computer.  Unbeknownst to them at that time, the next person to use the computer could potentially return to the same login page and be presented with the address of the pervious person.  If this is a problem to you, it might be worth adding an extra option to the login page which will allow the user to decide whether or not they want their email address remembered.

Comment: You could just put the email address in an instance variable instead of storing it in the session, this way it will only be available to the next request. Or use a form object to represent the login form which will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one small thing that concerns me. Imagine this scenario: an unkown user tries different email addresses and finds out that there is one exists say `john.smith@gmail.com`. Then all he needs to do is some phishing to get the password.

Would that be better to move `remembering emails` logic into a separate method, say a policy object, and check whether this user `john.smith@gmail.com` on this device `Mac OS`, with a given IP address `54.244.55.55` had at least 3 successful login attempts. That might decrease some security issues.

An articles about policy objects: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: There are two separate security issues here: (1) The message provided in response to a failed login attempt and (2) Whether the email entered should be pre-populated for the next attempt.

For (1) it is bad to say explicitly or imply that the email was correct and the password was wrong (and vice-versa), for the reason described by this answer. Best to leave it totally ambiguous which item was wrong. If pre-populating the email field implies anything, it might be bad. As for (2) I'll leave that to others to answer.

Comment: @Paul, totally. But Google keeps email if you are typed it correctly. And sends an email if you / anyone else entered via login on a different device / browser. Hence, I was just reverse engineering that logic. Hopefully I got it right :)